# Concatenating a row in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This seems like it should be so much simpler yet here I am.

I'm trying to add a row to a data frame (2 data frames to be exact) from another data frame, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'numpy.float64'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

My code

```
for i in range(0,len(k_means_labels_unique)):
    X = pd.DataFrame(columns=['first occurrence of \'AB\'','similarity to \'AB\''])
    y = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Class'])
    for row in result.iterrows():
        data=row[1]
        if data['cluster ID'] == i:
            X = pd.concat([X,data['first occurrence of \'AB\''],data['similarity to \'AB\'']])
            y = pd.concat([y,data['Class']])
```

Do I have to transform `data['first occurrence of \'AB\''],data['similarity to \'AB\'']` into another data frame? This seems horribly inefficient

EDIT: I tried `y = pd.concat([y,pd.Series(data['Class'])])` but that appended the data as a new column, example for `y`:

[image: columns]

Comment: try converting your vectors to pd.Series first: example : y = pd.concat([y,pd.Series(data['Class'])])

Comment: @CoMartel almost, but that seems to add the Series on as a new column (will update my question with a screenshot)

Comment: add sample input and expected output

Comment: My bad : I think you need to convert your data to a dataframe first. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first convert to dataframe :

```
X = pd.concat([X,pd.DataFrame([[data['first occurrence of \'AB\''],data['similarity to \'AB\'']]],columns=['first occurrence of \'AB\'','similarity to \'AB\''])], ignore_index=True)
y = pd.concat([y,pd.DataFrame([data['Class']], columns=['Class'])], ignore_index=True)
```

EDIT : add ignore_index=True

Comment: Ok so I tried this but I got this error instead:

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (2, 2)

Comment: on which line ?

Comment: on the X line (or if I comment out the X, I get "ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!" on the y line)

Comment: what does `data`look like ?

Comment: printed the first row: first occurrence of 'AB'   -1.000000
similarity to 'AB'          0.222222
Class                       0.000000
cluster ID                  0.000000
centroid_x                 -1.000000
centroid_y                  0.215873
Name: 0, dtype: float64

Comment: there's a line break after each number fyi (curse these one line comments!)

Comment: I added some missing [], can you try again ?